# Trigonometry : If tan aθ = tan bθ is a trigonometric equations and θ are in A.P. Then the general solution of θ is

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

My try : [image]

I have to proceed from here but I can't.
So please tell me the next steps or any other process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thus, $$(a-b)\theta=\pi k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Now, consider two cases:

1. $a-b=0$;
2. $a-b\neq0$.

Can you end it now?

Remember that $\cos a\theta\neq0$ and $\cos b\theta\neq0$

Comment: No, Michael I am unable to understand your process can u complete it

Comment: @user580093 Just the last expression in your trying is equal to $0$. Also, $\sin x=0$ it's $x=\pi k$. Draw the trigonometric circle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the signs or the fraction operations. It must be:
$$\tan a\theta=\tan b\theta \Rightarrow \frac{\sin a\theta}{\cos a\theta}=\frac{\sin b\theta}{\cos b\theta} \Rightarrow \frac{\sin a\theta}{\cos a\theta}-\frac{\sin b\theta}{\cos b\theta}=0 \Rightarrow \\
\frac{\sin a\theta\cos b\theta-\sin b\theta\cos a\theta}{\cos a\theta\cos b\theta}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{\sin (a\theta-b\theta)}{\cos a\theta\cos b\theta}=0 \Rightarrow \\
\sin (a\theta-b\theta)=0, \cos a\theta\ne 0, \cos b\theta\ne 0.$$
Can you finish?